# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a STRING value from a NUMERIC cell in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

// I have this method in one class

```
public class cls1 {
public void enterZip1(String zip1Value){
driver.findElement(zip1).sendKeys(zip1Value);
   }
}
```

// I have below snippet in another class.

```
public class cls2{

    Cell zip1Col = row.getCell(zip1ColNo);
    String zip1Value = zip1Col.getStringCellValue();
    cls1.enterZip1(zip1Value);

}
```

When I run my selenium webdriver script using Eclipse, I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a STRING value from a NUMERIC cell
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.typeMismatch(XSSFCell.java:1077)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.getRichStringCellValue(XSSFCell.java:395)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.getStringCellValue(XSSFCell.java:347)
    at com.carem.ss.dd(ss.java:215)
    ..........
```

Error is pointing to :

```
String zip1Value = zip1Col.getStringCellValue();
```

Data is coming from excel file. I have zip1 column in excel file. Zip1 cells have only numeric value. I know what causing the error but I am not able to fix it. Excel cell has numeric value but I declared a string variable. I  tried to change from

```
String zip1Value = zip1Col.getStringCellValue();
```

to

```
String zip1Value = zip1Col.getNumericCellValue();
```

Then I got lost because eclipse is recommending to make other changes including the above method. Excel will have always numeric value. How can I modify my code so it will accept the numeric value?

---

Update

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZgqm.png)

Comment: Try `String zip1Value = Integer.toString(zip1Col.getNumericCellValue());`

Comment: It did not fix. Please see the image.

Comment: Check [here](http://javadevnotes.com/java-double-to-string-examples) for various examples of converting a double to a string.

Comment: I am getting error because cell has numeric but code has string. So i need to be able to convert string to numeric. Your link converts double to string. Just confused. Some coding will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imported this:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.NumberToTextConverter;
```

Added this:

```
String zip1Value = NumberToTextConverter.toText(zip1Col.getNumericCellValue());
```

It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to your comments, and based upon the screenshot you gave me, the error specifically says that the value is a double.  Double is a kind of numeric value.  I originally incorrectly assumed that the value was an Integer (numeric) which is why my first suggestion did not work, but the following should work:

```
String zip1Value = Double.toString(zip1Col.getNumericCellValue());
```

Comment: I have zip code 22310 in the cell. zip1Value becomes 22103.0. I guess it is because double data type.

Comment: Yup.  Your own solution is the better solution for that reason.  There are other ways to convert from double to string using formatting which would have omitted the ".0" from the resulting string, but that's the nature of Java - there's almost always several ways to accomplish the same thing and you found the perfect one for your situation.